# Converting a PostgreSQL query with IN / NOT IN to JOINs

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I currently have two tables with the same structure. Table A (as an example) has 10,000 rows, table B has 100,000 rows. I need to obtain the rows that are in Table B that are not in Table A, but only if certain fields are the same (and one is not).

Right now, the query is something like:

```
select *
from tableA A
where (A.field1, A.field2) in (select field1, field2 from tableB B)
  and A.field3 not in (select field3 from B)
```

This works, but probably a better performant solution could be done with `JOIN`s. I have tried to do it but all I get is a very huge list of duplicated rows. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: And the field1 and field3 conditions are unrelated?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question as @jarlh: Are you sure your current query is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql - how to get entries in a table that do not have a match in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428966/postgresql-how-to-get-entries-in-a-table-that-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-t)

Comment: `that are in Table B that are not in Table A,`  ... this conflicts with your query. Did you swap A <--> B somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current query this is what it translates to as joins:

```
select * 
from tableA A
inner join tableB B on A.field1 = B.field1 and A.field2 = B.field2
left outer join tableB C on A.field3 = C.field3
where c.field3 is null
```

A faster query would be:

```
    select A.pk
    from tableA A
    inner join tableB B on A.field1 = B.field1 and A.field2 = B.field2
    left outer join tableB C on A.field3 = C.field3
    where c.field3 is null
    group by A.pk
```

This would give you the rows you need to add to tableB because they aren't found.

Or you can just get the fields you want to pull over:

```
    select A.field1, A.field2, A.field3
    from tableA A
    inner join tableB B on A.field1 = B.field1 and A.field2 = B.field2
    left outer join tableB C on A.field3 = C.field3
    where c.field3 is null
    group by A.field1, A.field2, A.field3
```

Comment: That's only an equivalent query if there's a guaranteed 1:1 relationship between `A` and `B` on the `(field1, field2)` join criteria.

Comment: Perhaps SELECT DISTINCT is needed. (Data dependant.)

Comment: Yes, I'm make an educated guess

Comment: This query takes a very long time to run and returns a lot of duplicated rows. My query or @joop's query works as expected (takes 6-7 secs). What do you think it is missing? A "SELECT DISTINCT" will also take a very very long time.

Comment: do you have an id column in tableA? because i would just select that instead of * and do a group by that column and that will be much quicker

Comment: Yes, both tables have a primary key, although the pk is not the same between tables (table A first row can have pk 100 while table B first row may have pk 250 for example).

Answer (score 0):

[NOT] EXISTS is your friend:

---

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tableB B
    WHERE A.field1 = B.field1
    AND A.field2 = B.field2
    )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tableB B 
    WHERE  A.field3 = B.field3 
    );
```

---

Note: if the joined columns are NOT NULLable, the `[NOT] EXISTS()` version will behave exactly the same as the `[NOT] IN` version

---

Reading the question text again (and again):

*I need to obtain the rows that are in Table B that are not in Table A, but only if certain fields are the same (and one is not).*

---

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB B
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tableA A
        WHERE A.field1 = B.field1
        AND A.field2 = B.field2 
        AND  A.field3 <> B.field3
        );
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this query takes the same time as the original.

Comment: Before complaining about performance, please correct your question first.